# What's the difference betwen i++ and i--

Tags: c++, for-loop

I've been messing around with `for` loops in C++. As you would expect, if I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << "Hi\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `"Hi"` 10 times.

But, let's say I decide to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i--)
        cout << "Hi\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to print `"Hi"` in the console window, but it seems to never stop. Why is that?

Can someone explain the difference between `i--` and `i++`, please?

Comment: `i--` decrements at each iteration, so `i` goes `0`, `-1`, `-2`... Note that the loop will eventually terminate once it rolls over after minimum value the int can represent; but on a 64 bit machine that'll take a long time.

Comment: --1 subtracts 1 from the operand and ++1 adds 1 to it.   You can see that if you start with zero and count backwards, it'll take a long time for the resulting negative numbers to overflow and turn into positive numbers, causing the loop to terminate.

Comment: See [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec). And you could try using a debugger or debug output in your code to see what is happening to `i`.

Comment: in case anybody is wondering, im using visual studio code as an ide

Comment: Then you should have a debugger at your disposal. Try putting a breakpoint on your `cout` line. Examine the value if `i` for a few iterations in the loop, and you should see what is happening to it.

Comment: Or, simply include the current value of `i` in your `cout` statement, eg: `cout << i << " Hi\n";`

Comment: im sorry how do you do that...

Comment: like how do you use the debugger ive never used it

Comment: I don't use Visual Studio myself, and it would be too much to address in a comment anyway. But you could try reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022

Comment: ok thank you! im really surprised at how i can get answers in less than 5 minutes on here anyways thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

`i++` means the same as `i += 1` and `i--` means the same as `i -= 1`

Comment: `i++` means the same as `[](int& j) { int old = j; j += 1; return old; }(i)`